# Run commands using cmd.exe with order

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to start or stop two services in this order: service1 then service2.
Here is my bat file(test.bat):
    `SET _cmd=net %1 service1 && net %1 service2`
    `cmd /C %_cmd%`

If run this bat like this: `test.bat start` or `test.bat stop`, the output looks as below:
    `starting/stopping service2`
    `starting/stopping service1`

However, what I want is service1 then service2. **Could anybody show me how to do that?**

If just run below command in a command prompt window, commands will run in right order:
    `cmd /c net stop service1 & net stop service2`

Anybody know the differences? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your batch file runs the two commands

```
SET _cmd=net %1 service1
net %1 service2
```

in that order. The `&&` does not become part of `_cmd`. Then, you run

```
cmd /C %_cmd%
```

which starts service1.

It seems to me the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
net %1 service1 && net %1 service2
```

There is no need to involve `cmd /c` or an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your clue!  Seems you are right, maybe the SET line will run as you said. Change the SET line as below will work:  `SET _cmd="net %1 service1 && net %1 service2"`